# How to Get Error Key From ResourceConfig.Resources in dotnet 6?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

in Resouces File We Have Key and Value
With Below Line I Can Show Value But Not Key ItSelf

```
result.WithSuccess(ResourceConfig.Resources.GetString("200"));
```

output : Susseccs
My desired output : Susscess , 200

I Try With
`GetObject` Too

Comment: What's `ResourceConfig`? The only references I've found for a class with this name are Java related, it doesn't seem to be a built it class in the .net Api

Comment: Related article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files

Comment: Still can't find `ResourceConfig` class in this article....

Comment: AFAICT, you could simply do `result.WithSuccess(ResourceConfig.Resources.GetString("200") + ", 200")`. But I guess, that is not what you meant. So it would be beneficial, if you could provide more context (code).